# How to delete all elements from a given list in Python?

Tags: python

I am receiving an list and a number as input parameters to a method:

```
def removeElement(nums: list[int], val: int):
```

I am trying to traverse thru all the elements of `nums` and remove all  of them if they are same.

```
def removeElement(nums: list[int], val: int):
    for i in nums:
        if i == val:
            nums.remove(i)
    print(nums)
    return nums
```

When I pass an array: `[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 4, 2]` and input val: `2`, I still last number `2` of the list in the output.
output: `[0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 2]`
[image]

Note: I shouldn't be using extra list or any other collection for space complexity.
Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am making here and how can I correct it ?

Comment: `return [i for i in nums if i != val]`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that when doing `for i in nums:`, `i` gets assigned to first element of `nums`, then 2nd etc, *even if* some elements are removed, that means in your case after removing the first 2 at 3rd position it moves to 4th position which is now a 3, so it skips the originally 4th 2.

To fix it you could count the number of occurrences of `val` and remove them afterwards accordingly :

```
def removeElement(nums: list[int], val: int):
    cnt = 0
    for i in nums:
        if i == val:
            cnt += 1
    for _ in range(cnt):
        nums.remove(val)
    print(nums)
return nums
```

Answer (score 2):

You are removing elements from the same list you are looping. This causes loop to end before it reaches the last element.

You can loop the array in reverse order and remove elements using index.

```py
def removeElement(nums, val):
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1):
        if nums[i] == val:
            del nums[i]
    return nums
```

Comment: This is `O(n)` and it is more elegant than the other solutions imho.

Answer (score 1):

`for i in nums` creates an iterator, which isn't modified for subsequent iterations. You can simply use a `while` loop with the `del` function to remove all target values.

```py
def removeElement(nums, val):
    i = 0
    while i<len(nums):
        if nums[i] == val:
            del nums[i]
        else:
            i += 1
    print(nums)
    return nums

removeElement([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 4, 2, 2], 2) #[0, 1, 3, 0, 4]
```

Comment: I tried it and it is working. But I shouldn't be using extra list or any collection for space complexity.

Comment: @Metadata add the constraint to the question then

Comment: Yeah, I added that point as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
def removeElement(nums, val):
    while val in nums:
        nums.remove(val)
    print(nums)
    return nums
```

This removes every `val` in `nums`

PS: This code is short and readable, but on large lists pretty slow.

Comment: Why would you add an extra `O(n)` operation to check if `val` is in `nums`? OP doesn't emphasize complexity optimization but this is even more inefficient than OP's implementation

Comment: Oh. I didnt think about this. You are absolutely right. XD

Comment: This solution can go `O(n²)` if all elements in the array are equal.

Comment: If `.remove()` is `O(n)` it can even reach `O(n³)`